# $AX = XA$, then show that $A^*X=XA^*$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $A \in M_{n\times n}$ be a normal matrix. If $X \in M_{n\times n}$ is any matrix such that $AX = XA$,
>   then show that $A^*X=XA^*$  .
>
> Is this true if A is any matrix?

Since $A$ is normal ,$AA^*=A^*A$.

Let $A=$ \begin{bmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13}\\a_{21} & a_{22} &a_{23}\\a_{31}& a_{32}& a_{33}\end{bmatrix}

I took as example $A,X$ to be $3\times 3$ matrix

$X=$  \begin{bmatrix} x_{11} & x_{12} & x_{13}\\x_{21} & x_{22} &x_{23}\\x_{31}& x_{32}& x_{33}\end{bmatrix}

But I could not find how to do it.

But how to show that $A^*X=XA^*$  .
Please help.

Comment: This is known as [Fuglede's Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuglede%27s_theorem) and the proof isn't exactly trivial. The way to go about it is to diagonalize $A$ and show that the eigenspace projection matrices commute with $X$, then from there you can argue that $A^*$ commutes with $X$.

Comment: @CameronWilliams; where can I find the proof of the theorem for matrices

Comment: You could just assume that $A$ is diagonal by the spectral theorem and study the commutation condition, you will see easily that the result follows, take your exemple $(3\times 3)$ 
but with $A$ diagonale...

Comment: Alternatively, since $A$ is normal, $A$ and $A^\ast$ are simultaneously diagonalisable. As $A$ and $A^\ast$ also have a one-one correspondence, $A^\ast$ is a Lagrange polynomial in $A$. Hence $AX=XA$ implies that $A^\ast X=XA^\ast$.

Answer (score 3):

By the [spectral theorem](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Linear_Algebra/Spectral_Theorem),
$$
A=\sum_{k=1}^n\lambda_k P_k
$$
where $P_k$ is a *projection matrix*, that is $P_k^*=P_k=P_k^2$, and $P_kP_l=0$ for $k\ne l$. The numbers $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n$ are the (pairwise distinct) *nonzero* eigenvalues of $A$.

Assuming $AX=XA$, we have
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \lambda_kP_kX=\sum_{k=1}^n \lambda_kXP_k
$$
Multiplying by $P_l$, we obtain
$$
\lambda_l P_lX=\lambda_lXP_l
$$
for $l=1,2,\dots,n$, which implies, as $\lambda_l\ne0$, that $P_lX=XP_l$.

Since $A^*=\sum_{k=1}^n\overline{\lambda_l}P_k$, the result should now be clear.

---

A hint for the proof of the top statement. Let $\lambda_0=0$ and $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n$ the (pairwise distinct) eigenvalues of $A$. Then you can build the unitary matrix $P$ diagonalizing $A$ by taking $m_k$ normalized eigenvectors relative to $\lambda_k$ (for $k=0,1,\dots,n$), where $m_k$ is the multiplicity of $\lambda_k$. Of course, if $0$ is not an eigenvalue, we'll have $m_0=0$.

Now just realize that the projection matrices $P_k$ on the eigenspaces do as required, using the fact that eigenvectors relative to distinct eigenvalues are orthogonal.

To make an example, suppose the eigenvalues are $\lambda$ and $\mu$, the former having multiplicity $2$ and the latter multiplicity $1$. Then
$$
P=[u_1 \ u_2 \ u_3]
$$
where $Au_1=\lambda u_1$, $Au_2=\lambda u_2$, $Au_3=\mu u_3$. Define
$$
P_1=u_1u_1^*+u_2u_2^*
\qquad
P_2=u_3u_3^*
$$
Note that
$$
P=P_1+P_2
$$
(why?) and that $P_1P_2=0=P_2P_1$. Then
$$
A=PDP^*=\lambda P_1+\mu P_2
$$
just by computing.

Comment: Since $A$ is normal so $A$ is orthogonally diagonalisable and hence $A=PDP^*$ where $P$ is an orthogonal matrix .

Comment: But how did you get that $A=\sum \lambda_kP_k$

Comment: @Student That's the spectral theorem, isn't it?

Comment: kindly explain how did you obtain that $A=\sum \lambda_kP_k$ from $A=PDP^*$ where $P$ is an unitary matrix

Comment: @Student I added a hint for the proof.

Comment: In the first line where $A=\sum_{k=1}^n\lambda_kP_k$ there were $n$ terms but in your example for a $3\times 3$ matrix we have only $P_1,P_2$

Comment: Also what is the general procedure to choose $P_i$  ?

Comment: Why can't we choose $P_i=u_iu_i^*$?

Comment: @Student $n$ is the number of nonzero eigenvalues. The $P_i$ matrices are the projection matrices on the eigenspaces.